# IISExpress - Localhost - ASP.NET MVC - 403 Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-403

Note: I know this has been covered multiple times on SO but I've been through all the relevant posts I could find and have not been able to find anything specific to my issue.

**Sometimes** when I start debugging my local MVC website, I get a 403 error and the only way to stop it from happening is to do a clean and build of the solution and then start debugging again. Note: I don't get a `403.??`, I just get a 403 with no subcode. I've looked at http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/testing-and-debugging/aspnet-web-pages-(razor)-troubleshooting-guide but this didn't help.

Note: I also updated one of my pre-production servers with this code and have seen the same thing happen on there (I had to re-upload cleaned DLLs).

Does anyone have any idea where to start debugging this? I can see my `Application_BeginRequest` being hit in my global file but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: any authorization issues? `https` may be? not sure.

Comment: do you get 403 on all websites during debugging? sometimes iis can be configured to throw 403 instead of 404 so make sure to enter existing url

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh No auth issues as far as I can see (And suspect a clean / build wouldn't fix it if it was).

Comment: @MichałW. - I only have one website running on my localhost but on my pre-production server, all other sites are working alongside this one not working.

Comment: can you try a different user for the app pool ?

Comment: Brute-force: you can incrementally revert and see what change is responsible for this, but as you said, its hard to reproduce. Maybe you started to access files in strange way - but the exception should be nicer. Folder access rights should not be the case when its same on pre-production. Check if you can find something in server log (output window on local)

Comment: @MichałW. Unfotunately, it's been happening for about a week (not entirely sure) and there are multiple people committing to the solution so reverting changes would be an absolute last resort as I don't have a consistent way to recreate it. I'll try the server log and see what that shows when it next happens.